# Woocommerce Attribute kept loading in adminpanel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Whenever I update the WooCommerce plugin it gets stucked in here with this problem.

While adding attributes in products it gets stucked and kept loading and nothing happen after as well.

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: Try checking the console in inspect elements for any warnings or errors

Comment: May be check first in WooCommerce > System Status … to see if there is not something wrong with your config

Comment: found the solution... Ultimate Addons Visual Composer causing the issue..by turning woopress off works

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when a plugin uses select2 v3 and loads it on WooCommerce screens. WooCommerce uses v4. The two are not compatible, and there is no possible shim to make them compatible. Downgrading to v3 is not an option.

To find the conflict you can either:

1. View the page source, find the select2.js/select2.min.js file and see where it comes from (it may be in a plugin directory)
2. Disable plugins/switch to default theme and re-enable things until the conflict occurs.

For More Details Visit : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14392

Comment: Visual Composer woopress causing the issue so i turned it off from UV Addons